# solve an integral equation $ \frac{1}{x}= \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \varphi(s,t,x)~dt~ds $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Can this equation be solved?

$$ \frac{1}{x}= \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \varphi(s,t,x)~dt~ds $$

> What kernel(s) give $1/x?$

I don't recognize the form of this integral equation which makes looking up the solution difficult.

Maybe finding a function that when integrated from $0$ to $\infty$ gives $1/x$ and then working one's way to the integral from $0$ to $1$ might help.

Comment: Do you want a function for $\varphi$ as your solution?

Comment: yes exactly that would be great

Comment: don't need all possible solutions - just one example

Comment: $\phi(s,t,x)=e^{-sx}$ is an example.

Comment: $\varphi (s,t,x) = \frac{2\exp(-s)t}{x}$ is another example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just take $\varphi(s,t,x) = \frac{1}{x}*\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}$, because $s,t,x$ are all independent $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{1}\varphi(s,t,x)dtds$ $ = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x}*\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}dtds$ $ =\frac{1}{x}*\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}(\int_0^{1}dt)ds$ $=\frac{1}{x}*\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}ds$ $=\frac{1}{x}$